# Get progress information using FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I posted successfully a photo via Facebook SDK into users photo album with the following code:

```
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil) {

        var filename = "2015-09-01T21-30-39_fullsize.jpg"
        let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
        let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(whagooConf.directoryMediaFiles)
        let filePath = dataPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
        var theImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)

        var params:NSMutableDictionary = [:]

        params["caption"] = "Test for my fist own app upload"
        params["picture"] = theImage

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                DebugOutput("ERROR -> \(error)")
            }
            else {
                DebugOutput("SUCCESS (result) -> \(result)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Now I´m searching for a solution, how to retrieve progress information from the `FBSDKGraphRequest` to show the user how long it will take. Does anyone have some hints or a solution?

Comment: Got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482699/get-progress-from-facebook-sdk-graphrequest-with-swift

Comment: Finally I wrote the answer to this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482699/get-progress-from-facebook-sdk-graphrequest-with-swift