# Get progress from Facebook SDK GraphRequest with swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I upload an image with this pice of code:

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print ("failed")
        }
        else {
            print ("success")
        }

    })
```

It works fine so far, but the upload can take a while and I want to inform the user about the current progress. Is there any way to get the current progress? As I can see in the SDK docs, there is a `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection` that provides a `FBSDKGraphRequestConnectionDelegate` with progress stuff in `requestConnection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`but I´m unable understand, how to implement this stuff in my little pice of code. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I someone else has the same problem ... Google does´t find anything written in swift. Here´s my working solution:

1) Derive your class from `NSObject` and `FBSDKGraphRequestConnectionDelegate`

2) Write your upload process like this:

```
    let uploadRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST")
    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
    connection.delegate = self
    connection.addRequest(uploadRequest, completionHandler: {
        (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            // error handling
        }
        else {
            // success handling
        }
    })
    connection.start()
```

3) Implement the delegate in your class like this:

```
func requestConnection(connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, didSendBodyData bytesWritten:NSInteger, totalBytesWritten:NSInteger, totalBytesExpectedToWrite:NSInteger) {
    print("upload percent reached: " + String(Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)))

    // handle your UI here to show the current status
}
```